# R shiny: How to create an output which serves as an input in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

My task is to:

- random two independent variables (A and B) from their normal distributions
- display their histograms,
- random 3rd variable (C) which distribution depends on the value B,
- display the histogram of C.
  I'd like all three histograms to be sensitive to changes in inputs.
  The histograms of A and B are reactive.
  What can I do with C? Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my try:

ui:

```
   library(shiny)
   fluidPage(
   titlePanel("Random"),

   sidebarLayout(
   sidebarPanel(
   sliderInput("obs", 
              "Number of observations:", 
              min = 1,
              max = 100, 
              value = 50)
),

mainPanel(
  tabsetPanel(type="tabs",
              tabPanel("plot 1 and plot 2",plotOutput("plot1"), plotOutput("plot2")),
              tabPanel("plot 3",plotOutput("plot3"))
  ))))
```

server:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
output$plot1 <- renderPlot({

 {
  values_B <-rnorm(input$obs, 25,6) 
  assign('B_values', round(values_B), envir=.GlobalEnv)
  hist(B_values, main="Histogram of B values", xlab="values")}
 })
  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({ 
  values_A<-rnorm(input$obs,20, 4.5) 
  assign('A_values', round(values_A), envir=.GlobalEnv)
  hist(A_values, main="Histogram of A values", xlab="values")
 })
 output$plot3 <- renderPlot({
category <- function(x) if ( x <=10) round(rnorm(1,50,10)) else  round(rnorm(1,10,2))
assign('C_values', as.numeric(lapply(B_values, category)))
hist(C)
 })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this isn't working is because you need to create a reactive variable with your B_values as you cannot define a reactive variable within the renderPlot function and use it again therefore your code won't work in plot 3 as you have the dependency on the variable in plot1. You must define this as a reactive value as shown and then call it in your renderPlot.

Note that when calling a reactive variable you must use brackets after the variable name.

I would recommend that you watch the shiny tutorial on the shiny website it is very helpful in understanding how reactivity works.

Here is the server side for your example such that it works.

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

reactiveB <- reactive({
    rnorm(input$obs, 25,6)
})

output$plot1 <- renderPlot({

 {

  values_B <- reactiveB() 
  assign('B_values', round(values_B), envir=.GlobalEnv)
  hist(B_values, main="Histogram of B values", xlab="values")}
 })
  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({ 
  values_A<-rnorm(input$obs,20, 4.5) 
  assign('A_values', round(values_A), envir=.GlobalEnv)
  hist(A_values, main="Histogram of A values", xlab="values")
 })
 output$plot3 <- renderPlot({
B_values <- reactiveB()
category <- function(x) if ( x <=10) round(rnorm(1,50,10)) else  round(rnorm(1,10,2))
assign('C_values', as.numeric(lapply(B_values, category)))
 hist(C_values)
})
})
```